# in typescript can we convert two enums into one object key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have two enums Key & Label and an interface IOption and using enums i want create an Iptions object of array

```
const enum Key {
    Flag = 'flag',
    Checkbox = 'checkbox',
    Star = 'star'
}

const enum Label {
    Flag = 'Flag',
    Checkbox = 'Checbox',
    Star = 'Start'
}

interface IOption {
  key: Key;
  label: Label;
}

const dropDowOptions: Ioptions[]
```

what is the best way to achieve an array of IOption like this

```
const dropDownOptions = [
                         {myKey: Key.Flag,  myLabel: Label.Flag },
                         {myKey: Key.Star, myLabel: Label.Flag},
                         {myKey: Key.CheckBox, myLael: Label.Checkbox}  
                         ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this:

```
enum Key {
    Flag = 'flag',
    Checkbox = 'checkbox',
    Star = 'star'
}

enum Label {
    Flag = 'Flag',
    Checkbox = 'Checbox',
    Star = 'Start'
}

interface IOption {
  key: Key;
  label: Label;
}

var dropDownOptions: IOption[] = new Array<IOption>();

Object.keys(Key).forEach(key => {
    dropDownOptions.push({
        key: Key[key],
        label: Label[key]
    });
});
console.log(dropDownOptions);
```

Output:

```
[
  { key: 'flag', label: 'Flag' },
  { key: 'checkbox', label: 'Checbox' },        
  { key: 'star', label: 'Start' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly you want to change the interface to describe the constant `dropDownOptions` ... you can do it like so

```
interface IOption {
    myKey: Key;
    myLabel: Label;
}


// what is the best way to achieve an array of IOption like this

const dropDownOptions: IOption[] = [
    { myKey: Key.Flag, myLabel: Label.Flag },
    { myKey: Key.Star, myLabel: Label.Flag },
    { myKey: Key.Checkbox, myLabel: Label.Checkbox }
]
```

[working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgaTgTxgbwLABQMxMAYgDYCGA5jALwwDkAZldYwDSEkwDCAFnGABrAEYgAHvSbBBI8RM7cSAZSiUATtMbRNjQgF9ChUJFgIUMADKVRccrmXEKNbS-ZciJAULGTtPsAKSl7Eapra4RpQ+gRGBIQAlmBQcBrMlMBwMACSAPIADlCJ4I6hMMiYGJgAXOhYANxOFZg2duR1bfZNccYJBAD0AzAA7vyUsIkQMFCCMHbQo5TYUCAwmfyJcABu2ZRg6xoayzAgzLmFxaXkicLZs1N9posAJhogBQAiICNglyWQOr5IoAgDaAF1pKDmjgWtU6tUAHTuDgtLoday2ezItgwAyeHiwyrw+qYRFRVGVdGdLHkHGufEwuFYBFYRGBPwSSmtWk09rsuScvGEcGEIA)